# Permission requests are not propagated when launching with flutter but are when launching with android directly

Tags: android, flutter

I try to request permissions to use location data with a flutter app. I am using the [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) plugin and [permission_handler](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler). Both added to my `pubspec.yaml`.

I have futhermore added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

to my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

The first thing I do when I launch my app, is

```
PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]).then((val) {
  ...
});
```

If I then run this on either an emulator or on my physical phone, it returns a `PermissionStatus.unknown` and subsequent calls to `GeoLocator()` spams the console with

```
No permissions found in manifest for: $permission
```

If I go into app-settings it says that no special permissions were requested.

When I then open up the exact same project as an Android project (I am using Android Studio for both, there is a neat dropdown option to open Android project in Android Studio) and run it on my phone it works as expected - it asks for the permission and if I go into the app-settings I can also see the requested permission there.

Anyone have any idea why it does not get "propagated" with flutter?

Comment: I think in the flutter project in the android folder structure there is another Manifest.xml which is the one that gets coppied and overwrites the other one - basically do not change anything in the actualy android project as it gets overwritten  on flutter build

Comment: how did you run flutter project, with `flutter run`?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I can find one in `android/app/src/debug/`, `android/app/src/profile` and `android/app/src/main`. I have tried all three without luck. Am I missing one?

@TruongSinh Tried both commandline and Android Studio's run-button.

Comment: have you tried changing something else (is it jus tthe manifest permissions that dont get updated or the rest as well ?)

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I just tried to change the `android:label` but it was also not reflected in the emulator. I looks like the whole AndroidManifest is not updated.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I tried to do a `flutter clean` and then rebuild, and this time it updated. I am not sure whether this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like the main issue is that the AndroidManifest.xml is not updated when simply relaunching the application. If, however, one first do a `flutter clean` and then rebuilds it, the AndroidManifest.xml is updated.

I am not sure if this the intended behavior, but it works. Just something to remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Cleaning the project and reinstalling it worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just perform the following command at your command line

`flutter clean`

after adding permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

You just need to perform the two steps:

1. Add the permissions in the android manifest file.
2. Execute the command **flutter clean** in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Take it as a basic rule, after updating the manifest u have to clean the project.

Comment: Who did vote down my comment, review the correct answer first bro it is the same 